# "Value does not fall in expected range" List collection and not in Observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, list, exception, observablecollection

This is my working code,

```
private ObservableCollection<User> _Users;
public ObservableCollection<User> Users 
{ 
     get { return _Users; } 
     set { _Users = value; RaisePropertyChanged(()=> Users); } 
}

Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Users.Add(new User()
    {
        ADDRESS_LINE_1 = "Test Address",
        ADDRESS_LINE_2 = "Test Address 2",
        FIRST_NAME = "Test Name " + i,
        SURNAME = "Test surname " +i,
        DATE_OF_BIRTH = DateTime.Now.Date,
        GENDER = "M",
        MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER = "+1100000",
        EMAIL_ADDRESS = "Test@email.com",
        LAST_MODIFIED = DateTime.Now,
        LOGIN_NAME ="operator.domain.com",
        ItemIndex = Users.Count +1

    });
}
```

earlier i am using

```
private List<User> _Users;
public List<User> Users 
{ 
    get { return _Users; } 
    set { _Users = value; RaisePropertyChanged(()=> Users); } 
}

Users = new List<User>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    Users.Add(new User()
    {
        ADDRESS_LINE_1 = "Test Address",
        ADDRESS_LINE_2 = "Test Address 2",
        FIRST_NAME = "Test Name " + i,
        SURNAME = "Test surname " +i,
        DATE_OF_BIRTH = DateTime.Now.Date,
        GENDER = "M",
        MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER = "+9100000",
        EMAIL_ADDRESS = "Test@email.com",
        LAST_MODIFIED = DateTime.Now,
        LOGIN_NAME ="operator1.domain.com",
        ItemIndex = Users.Count +1
    });
}
```

and i am continuously getting following exception message, when i try to bind it with datatemplate in xaml

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Stack trace is null :(

In addition, if i take another list variable and add those values to it and then assign  shallow copy of that list to the my above list, the code give me desired result, but again what actually going around.

This is the datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="-8,-10,-8,-10" Background="{Binding ItemIndex, Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundConverter}}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleForAdmin}" Background="{Binding ItemIndex, Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundConverter}}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <!--<Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.3" Visibility="{Binding IsSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ControlVisibiltyOfSelectedItemInListBox}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ArrowGlyph}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>-->
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCell}" Text="{Binding SURNAME}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleForAdmin}" Background="{Binding ItemIndex, Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCell}" Text="{Binding FIRST_NAME}"></TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleForAdmin}" Background="{Binding ItemIndex, Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCell}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Run Text="{Binding ADDRESS_LINE_1}"></Run><LineBreak></LineBreak>
                         <Run Text="{Binding ADDRESS_LINE_2}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleForAdmin}" Background="{Binding ItemIndex, Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCell}" Text="{Binding DATE_OF_BIRTH}"></TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleForAdmin}" Background="{Binding ItemIndex, Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCell}" Text="{Binding EMAIL_ADDRESS}"></TextBlock>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleForAdmin}" Background="{Binding ItemIndex, Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowBackgroundConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockCell}" Text="{Binding MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER}"></TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Though, Observable collection works for me but i am wondering why List giving me this exception, i am unable to figure out what's the actual reason behind the scene. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you getting error?

Comment: on binding that collection to my data template in xaml.
@ Karl Anderson - MOBILE_PHONE_NUMBER is string

Comment: Could you write a minimal project that can reproduce this issue? I am unable to reproduce it with your posted code, it works with List<T>, as long as the binding and template are correctly written.

Comment: please add the DataTemplate of the ListBox and the full StackTrace of the exception you get

Comment: what value has the `ItemIndex` property? Where do you set it? Is it possible that your `AlternateRowBackgroundConverter` throws the Exception?

Comment: sorry i update my code, actually that was my new implementation, anyway that was not a problem i am sure

Comment: try and change the ItemIndex property name to just Index as it can be a collision with the ItemIndex property of the ItemsControl.

Comment: no Pedro, that is not the issue, as i said above ItemIndex  is my new implementation this has nothing to do with error. Does anybody able to replicate this issue ??

Comment: can you paste your code for AlternateRowBackgroundConverter and put a break point in it and see if the error appear just after exiting thins

Comment: Again, a short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be *really* helpful.

Comment: try removing the + from your telephone number and see if it does something...

Comment: With so many resources referenced, we cannot figure out the error without additional information. Check if any of those styles you reference, uses any image and if yes, check that the path and syntax is valid. Just a blind shot, but I've seen this error in that context before.

Comment: what is ControlVisibiltyOfSelectedItemInListBox ? May be it is casting to wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing which bugs me out here is "`RaisePropertyChanged`" is used with `ObservableCollection` or at least you must inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. In your second implementation list is not getting "RaisePropertyChanged" method. Consider list declaration as:

```
private List<User> _Users;
public List<User> Users 
{ 
    get { return _Users; } 
    set { _Users = value;} 
}
```

I think this should resolve the error. But **NOTE** that doing so will not raise PropertyChanged event whenever the state of the object changes (Added, Removed, and Modified) to the point where you want to notify the underlying collection or container that the state has changed.

For more info read: [List vs ObservableCollection vs INotifyPropertyChanged in Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha)

Comment: thanku for your response but i am using mvvmlight, RaisePropertyChanged is genric implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, and in both cases RaisePropertyChanged triggers but error come's while binding i think. I used both type of collections but never get such error before. The real question is why it is working with ObservableCollection and not with List.